# Changed form after publishing in infopath

Tags: sharepoint

I have published a form in InfoPath.The form looks diffent in couple places in the browser in a sharepoint  (a lack of colours in a columns and in a rows)

Comment: Please give a pic to help you

Comment: I was doing everything manually in InfoPath without writing a code . Do u mean a file with a template ?

Comment: This's a infopath common problem with styles. Sometimes it doesn't show colors, borders, paddings in browser. Try to remove colors from form, publish it, then return colors and publish again. Or you'll have to add css styles to xml.